# SlidingDrawer move over the original screen

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

My application contains a screen which contains a horizental SlidingDrawer.
When user perss on the drawer handle, the drawer should "cover" the whole screen. when it closed, the "original" screen should reveal.
I have located the drawer in a FrameLayout but the handle disappeared.

How it can resolved?

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 3):

Funny, I just solved this problem not to long ago. It took me a little while but after some Googling and testing I came up with this:

Basically I put my entire layout into a "Relative Layout" and then created a "Linear Layout" inside of that for the main stuff. Inside the "Relative Layout" but outside of the "Linear Layout" I put my "SlidingDrawer". I am showing the buttons and handle in the xml below. Also, I created a "Linear Layout" in my "SlidingDrawer" for content.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 ..stuff for the main screen

</LinearLayout>
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/list_background"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="My App"
        android:textSize="7pt" >
    </Button>
    <LinearLayout>

        ...sliding drawing is at the bottom
    ...stuff in here will be in the sliding drawer

    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Before posting this, I just ran my test application with this code and it works. If you have any questions, please ask and I hope this helps.

[image]